# Using Xamarin.Forms controls in native Xamarin.Android project?

Tags: xamarin.forms, android-activity, xamarin.android

Let me explain the current situation here.
I have a main Xamarin.Forms project that consists of a main UI contentpage that is also being used by the Native Projects, because this is how a Xamarin.Forms project works.

The thing is that I want to use a control (such as a Label) that is being used in the MainPage.xaml of the main Xamarin.Forms project within the native Xamarin.Android project, inside MainActivity.cs. Within MainActivity.cs I want to update the value of the control, so that this is being displayed on the UI..

I have named the label as 'lblTest', however MainActivity.cs is unable to find this control. This makes sense of course, because this control does not exist within the Xamarin.Android project.

Do you have any idea how I can access this Xamarin.Forms control within a native Xamarin.Android project? I would appreciate this and thanks in advance.

Comment: you want to display the Forms Label in a native Android layout?  Or you just want to update the value of the Forms Label from within MainActivity?  Or if neither of those, please be more specific about exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to update within MainActivity.cs the value of the label..

Comment: I'd suggest using `MessagingCenter` to send a message from `MainActivity` to the page with the data you want to update, then let that page take care of updating it's own UI.  You could do it directly from within `MainActivity` but it's a messy solution that tightly couples those two classes together

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll wait for other answers too which might be a better solution as you're pointing out yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jason mentioned , `MessagingCenter`  is a working but messy solution.

Another way is to get access the page first and then  update the Label in a public method which is defined inside the page .

For example , if the page is MainPage of App, you can define a public method first .

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

//used to update the label
public void updateLabel(string data)
{
   lblTest.Text = data; 
}
```

And update the label in Android project.

```
((App.Current as App).MainPage as YourPage).updateLabel("the data you want to update");
```

Comment: Oké, I'll let you as soon as possible know to see whether this works or not in my current context. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: ColeX - MSFT,  Thank you so much. This worked very well and clean. I wasn't aware of such solution. I'm also curious, why are you using this part of the code '((App.Current as App).MainPage as YourPage)', what's the purpose? Is it looking in the current application's context to receive which initial page is being used for all platforms? In the documentation: [Application.Current Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.current?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) it says something about shared resources and state, are all pages gathered and saved within this domain?

Comment: In other words: are all pages and other resources that are currently being used by the current application available from this property?

Comment: Another way (longer version) of doing this for those to understand your used method, could be something like this right? `MainPage mainPage = (App.Current as App).MainPage as MainPage; mainPage.updateLabel("test message");`

Comment: Briefly speaking the class App exists always along with the Application and will never be released , so we can retrieve current application's context and then get the `MainPage` which is defined as public property , and do what you want .

Comment: All right, thanks for the effort. I'm really appreciating it!